# Unable to login as Admin

Tags: android, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, long-integer

In my app, I can log in as the user or admin. I can successfully log in as a user but I am getting an error while trying to log in as an admin in my app. Even tho I enter the correct credentials, I am being redirected to the Launcheractivity The error says cannot convert Long to String but I have not used Long anywhere. 
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oid5o.jpg)

loginactivity

```
public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword;
    private Button LoginButton;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private TextView AdminLink, NotAdminLink;



    private String parentDbName = "Users";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login_btn);
        InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_Password_input);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        AdminLink = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.admin_panel_link);
        NotAdminLink = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.not_admin_panel_link);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        Paper.init(this);

        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                LoginUser();
            }
        });

        AdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                 LoginButton.setText("Login Admin");
                 AdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 NotAdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 parentDbName = "Admins";


            }
        });

                NotAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        LoginButton.setText("Login");
                        AdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        NotAdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        parentDbName = "Users";
                    }
                });


    }


    private void LoginUser()
    {
        String phone = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();

          if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your phone...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                 else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
          {
              loadingBar.setTitle("Login Account");
              loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are Checking the Credential");
              loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
              loadingBar.show();

              AllowAccessAccount(phone, password);
          }
    }

        private void AllowAccessAccount(final String phone, final String password)
        { final DatabaseReference RootRef;
            RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                       if(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).exists())
                       {
                           Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);
                           if (usersData != null)
                           {
                               if (usersData.getPhone().equals(phone))
                               {
                                   if (usersData.getPassword().equals(password))
                                   {

                                       if (parentDbName.equals("Admins"))
                                       {
                                           Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Welcome Admin, you are Logged in Successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           loadingBar.dismiss();

                                           Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                                           startActivity(intent);
                                       }
                                       else if (parentDbName.equals("Users"))
                                       {
                                           Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           loadingBar.dismiss();

                                           Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                           Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
                                           startActivity(intent);
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Password is Incorrect..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   loadingBar.dismiss();
                               }
                           }


                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this,"Account with This" + phone + " number do not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           loadingBar.dismiss();
                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
        }
}
```

An error displayed in the Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ecommerce1, PID: 4921
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String at com.example.ecommerce1.loginActivity$4.onDataChange(loginActivity.java:123)
```

User(Model Class)

```
package com.example.ecommerce1.Model;

public class Users {
    private String name, phone, password, image,address;

    public Users()
    {

    }

    public Users(String name, String phone, String password, String image, String address)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.password = password;
        this.image = image;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: At which particular line of does that error occur? Besides that, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: The error is in this line.  'Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);'

Comment: Ok, but please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Yes i just did that, you can check it above or over [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oid5o.jpg](here)

Comment: In your Users model in application is String or Long type?

Comment: it is String type

Comment: I think I get it but to be sure, please also add the content of your `Users` class and please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: can u log `usersData` and tell us what you get

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the Users Model Class

Answer (score 0):

phone in your database is of type `Long` and phone in your `Users` POJO class is of type `String`, you need to change the type in your POJO class to `Long`:

```
Long phone
```

---

The other solution is to keep it as `String`, but when saving you can use the pojo class to save to the database, example:

```
Users newUser = new Users("peter","1234556","1232135","image_url","Living_in_StackOverflow_24/7")
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Admin").child("1234556").setValue(newUser);
```

Comment: How do I change the type of phone to String in the Database, I appreciate your answer but I am calling the value as a child later in my application, and while calling the child it comes as String.Also I am surprised that the phone is stored as Long in the database because I have defined it as String in the registration activity.

Comment: the phone is of type String, you need to change it to type Long. When you are calling from the database you are retrieving it of type Long, but in your POJO you have it as String thus you got that error

Comment: Ok understood but after changing it to Long I am getting this error everywhere where I am calling it as a child in my app `error: incompatible types: Long cannot be converted to String`

Comment: okay then the best solution, is to keep it as `String`, and when you save data to the database you can save it as `String`

Comment: But that is my confusion, I am saving it as String only. I habe not made use of Long in the Register Code